# Running .net core application on a chromebook

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, chromebook

I have developed a asp.net 5 web application with only .net core components, how can i run it on a Chromebook as a standalone application.

Comment: There's no official support for Chromebook

Comment: Are there any alternate ways to do it ?

Comment: @srivatsa6065 the source code of both are open, so hack them. Or I should say that Google Native Client is powered by Mono, which is a variation of .NET.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old - however there have been some updates since it was originally asked.  Here is an ARM build of .net core that can run on Raspberry PI, Chromebook or any other Ubuntu 16.04 ARM based Linux OS.

https://github.com/stevedesmond-ca/dotnet-arm

Answer (score 1):

You can install [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) on your chromebook and then follow the instructions [to install .NET Core on Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux).

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably aren't going to like this answer, but its currently the only 'supported' solution for chromebooks for the time being: **Virtual Machines**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-virtual-machine/

There are numerous options out there. It just depends on what you have access to and what sort of budget you have.